# Clicking in Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, vba

I have to write simple program for clicking in Internet Explorer, have started, but due to my little experience in programming, stucked. On the first page 11.html I need to click button with text "Sign1", on the next "Sign2"

```
//11.html    
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="document.location='21.html'" value="Sign1"> 

//21.html    
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="document.location='31.html'" value="Sign2">
```

What is wrong? Second button is not working.

```
Public Class Form1 Public ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate("http://....com/11.html")
    Do
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    Actions()
End Sub

Private Sub Actions()
    Dim eInputs = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each eInput In eInputs
        If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign1" Then
            eInput.Click()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

    //here ie href is about:blank - WHY???
    eInputs = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each eInput In eInputs
        If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign2" Then
            eInput.Click()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I don't think Cyrillic alphabet can be hardcoded. That's what it should be wrong, the compiler will compile them as "???????"

Comment: Thanks for your reply Cyrillic alphabet doesn't play any role: If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign1" Then... If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign2" Then...

Comment: In the second part ie variable href property is about:blank. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems here:

- Cyrillic alphabet:

  ```
  If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Подписать2" Then
  ```

  I don't think you can hard-code these characters into the source code,
  because they will not be read by the compiler. Hence, it's highly possible that the `getAttribute` method is returning the correct string but then it's comparing it against a `??????` one so it doesn't find it. Maybe, you might want to get them from an external source (a `txt` file, a database etc.).
- No waiting time between the two buttons:

  As you say *Second button is not working.* (very broad definition: is doing anything? Is raising an error?), I assume the first is. Hence, it might be you found already a way to work-around the alphabetic problem. 
  So I think the issue is that *you don't wait enough time between one click and the other, so the page is not loaded yet when you want to click the second button.*.

  Basically:

  1) You click the button 1 in the client (let's say Google Chrome);

  2) The button 1 click calls an action in the back-end, so the server will start  generate the new HTML document in which you look for button 2;

  3)... however, you don't give the server any time for regenerating the page so you already look for the button 2, which probably does not exist yet in your client because the server did not end the regeneration.

  So, that's why it doesn't work. If this is the case, add a command to wait some time before to look for the button 2. It's not clear in which language you're developing since you referenced all the .NET languages, but looking at the code I can recognize VB.NET.

Hence, to wait 5 seconds in VB.NET before running the second part of the code:

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

to be put between the first and the second `For Loop`

Comment: Cyrillic alphabet doesn't play any role:

Comment: Thanks for your reply
Cyrillic alphabet doesn't play any role: 
If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign1" Then...
If eInput.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign2" Then...
I've tried to wait between 1 and 2 part, but second part still not working. It's like ie.Document remains the same, though url has changed after first click. Any idea?

Comment: In the second part ie variable href property is about:blank